# Selenium Chromedriver Won't Keep Me Logged In When Interacting With Website... Sometimes

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm creating a program through Microsoft Excel VBA using Selenium Chromedriver. The program aims to take information from a Spreadsheet, create links, then open the pages and fill form fields with information from the spreadsheet. I've been able to get most all of the functionality to work, with one annoying hiccup. Each time the program opens a new link, the website signs me out of my profile and returns it to the default Guest profile.

```
Sub startingout()

Dim URL As String
Dim driver As New WebDriver

driver.Start "Chrome", ""

driver.Get "https://website.com/default.aspx"

driver.FindElementByName("ctl00$LoginForm$UserName").SendKeys ("username")
driver.FindElementByName("ctl00$LoginForm$Password").SendKeys ("password")
driver.FindElementByName("ctl00$LoginForm$LoginButton").Click

URL = "https://website.com/specificURL"

Call secondtest(driver, URL)

End Sub


Sub secondtest(driver As WebDriver, URL As String)

driver.Get URL

driver.FindElementByName("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lvItems$ctrl0$TextBoxQty").SendKeys ("1")
driver.FindElementByName("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lvItems$ctrl0$btnAddCart").Click
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
driver.FindElementByName("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnContinue").Click
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:1"))

End Sub
```

Above is the test code that works fine. I stay logged in. The actual program is a sub procedure that calls one of three other sub procedures when the link is created. Below is how I began the main sub procedure, to load up the website.

```
Dim driver As New WebDriver

driver.Start "Chrome", ""

driver.Get "https://website.com/default.aspx"

driver.FindElementByName("ctl00$LoginForm$UserName").SendKeys ("username")

driver.FindElementByName("ctl00$LoginForm$Password").SendKeys ("password")

driver.FindElementByName("ctl00$LoginForm$LoginButton").Click
```

Once the link is created, it moves to another sub procedure that starts as follows:

```
Sub FullBar(URL As String, Quantity As Integer, CurRow As Integer, driver As 
WebDriver)

Dim gotit As Boolean

gotit = False

driver.Get URL
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
```

Now, it does not seem that these two cases are fundamentally different, yet they act like they are. The strange thing about this is that when I create a test program using just VBA and some test links, I am able to stay logged in just fine. Why is this, and what makes the two situations different?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really figure out why this is happening, but I did find a solution. I followed this page:

https://www.reddit.com/r/vba/comments/a63c2k/open_chrome_and_set_profile_with_chromedriver/

I created a new chrome profile and loaded from there, adding the

```
bot.addArguments("--no-sandbox")
```

to the code. It could be that the Selenium doesn't like using the default program or something. Anyway, I got it to work and I stay logged in.